# Threading iPhone

Tags: ios, multithreading

Say I have a group of large meshes that I have to intersect rays against.  Assume also, for whatever reason, I cannot further simplify/reduce poly check count by spatial subdivisioning.  I can do this in parallel:

```
bool intersects( list of meshes ) // a mesh is a group of triangles
{
    create n threads

    foreach mesh in meshes 
        assign to a thread in threads

    wait until ( threads.run() ) ; // run asynchronously

    // when they're all done
    // pull out intersected triangles
    // from per-thread context data
}
```

Can you do this in ios for games?  Or is the overhead of thread creation and mutex waiting going to beat-out the benefit of multithreading?

Answer (score 1):

If your array is a NSArray, use method like -enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:.
This method will use GCD and will dispatch enumeration to different cores, according to number of CPU cores and the array size.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone has 2 cores. Your code looks more like you have 8 or 16 cores.
If you have 2 cores then you may split app in animation and physics threads.
Physics thread would be connected with animation thread with 2 channels (pipes)

Everyframe animation will write commands/messages to pipe and read messages
Message may contain anything.

Object A
Position 
Time
Velocity

So if phsyics do not give update for object A then animation thread will be able to interpolate position for every frame knowing it original position at a time, ceocity and current time.

With that system you can outsource any tasks to second thread.

But high frame rate is most important. It is more important then long time waiting.